# Issue with Socket.io in a React/Node project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I created an Express server that listens to a Twitch Channel and get all the messages written on the chat,

I want to send these messages to my React App, but I never get those in the app,

Server-side code

```
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  const server = require("http").Server(app);
  const io = require("socket.io")(server);

  io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  const client = new tmi.Client({
    connection: {
      reconnect: true,
      secure: true,
    },
    identity: {
      username: "BotVersi",
      password: process.env.TMI_PASSWORD,
    },
    channels: ["versifixion"],
  });

  client.connect().catch(console.error);

  client.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
      if (self) return;
      const objectMessage = { content: message, writer: tags.username };

      // HERE I WANT TO EMIT SEND MESSAGE ANS SEND THE ObjectMessage OBJECT TO CLIENT
      io.emit("send message", objectMessage);
    }
  });
});
```

Client-side code

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
    socket.on("send message", (data) => {
      setMessages([...messages, data]);
    });
  }, []);
```

**There are no errors, just I can't get the messages sent from the server to the app...**

**The server is running on http://localhost:5000 and the process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL in the client is equal to http://localhost:5000**

Comment: to have a socket connection to your backend , you need to use `ws` instead of `http` .

Comment: the socket.io package is not enough for the backend ?

Comment: I am not familiar with that library . But we can't transfer messages to a websocket server via http . Because the protocol's are different since socket is a duplex connection .

Comment: Ok, I just added some code to show that I imported the socket io package, but I'l look into it